# What does INSTALLED_APPS setting in Django actually do?

Tags: python, django

What does this *actually* do? I recently branched out my project from 1 app into 6 different apps and forgot to update the `INSTALLED_APPS` part of my settings file. Everything still works even though I didn't list the new apps in. Is that supposed to happen? Do I need to include all my apps in `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

yes.

INSTALLED_APPS helps django to sync the database, run tests, get the urls to work and more related issues.

Maybe your installed apps still works because the main one calls the others with imports, a django app is nothing more that a simple **python module** that is imported when called in the settings file, that's why you get a invalid syntax error after you run the development server because an import won't work with invalid syntax.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am changing the URLS now and templates and it's starting to mess up.